# Find key in std::set with custom comparator

Tags: c++, stl, set, comparator

I've a class named `Example` with two integer elements `a` and `b` creating a `set` with that class and customized `comparator`. The `comparator` is used the second variable `b` as a higher priority with descending order. If the value is identical then first variable will be prioritize with higher value. Here is my code:

[C++ 14 ISO]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Example
{
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
        Example(int x, int y) { a=x; b=y; }
};

class Comparator
{
    public:
        using is_transparent = true_type;

        bool operator()(const int &left, const Example& right) const
        {
            if(left > right.b) return true;
            if(left == right.b) return left > right.a ? true: false;

            return false;
        }

        bool operator()(const Example& left, const int& right) const
        {
            if(left.b > right) return true;
            if(left.b == right) return left.a > right ? true: false;

            return false;
        }

        bool operator()(const Example& left, const Example& right) const
        {
            if(left.b > right.b) return true;
            if(left.b == right.b) return left.a > right.a ? true: false;

            return false;
        }
};

int main()
{
    set<Example, Comparator> sa;
    sa.emplace(Example(4,3));
    sa.emplace(Example(1,2));
    sa.emplace(Example(5,3));
    sa.emplace(Example(2,7));
    sa.emplace(Example(3,1));

    for(auto it=sa.begin(); it!=sa.end(); it++)
        cout<< it->a <<" "<< it->b<<endl;

    cout<<"Find: "<<endl;
    auto it=sa.find(3);
    if(it!=sa.end())
        cout << it->a<<" " << it->b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 7
5 3
4 3
1 2
3 1
Find:
```

It dose not find the value `3` with the above comparator.
Anybody tell me, how can I find the first value with variable `a` in the class `Example` using `set` data while customized comparator is used?

When I use below comparator is working well while sorted in ascending and descending order compared with only first variable `a`.

```
class Comparator
{
    public:
        using is_transparent = true_type;

        bool operator()(const int & left, const Example& right) const
        {
            return left < right.a;
        }

        bool operator()(const Example & left, const int& right) const
        {
            return left.a < right;
        }

        bool operator()(const Example& left, const Example& right) const
        {
            return left.a < right.a;
        }
};
```

Output:

```
1 2
2 7
3 1
4 3
5 3
Find:
3 1
```

Comment: `3` would be equivalent to `Example(3, 3)` with your comparator, which does not exist in the set.

Comment: btw `return left > right.a ? true: false;` is just `return left > right.a;`

Comment: you could use `std::find_if` but then maybe `std::set` is the wrong container

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes, only relational operator is enough here for boolean output. I think `std::find_if` is linear in complexity with O(n).

Answer (score 2):

This implementation cannot work. The 2 comparator functions with the `int`  on the left or right side, have a wrong comparison.

You can only compare to one value. It does not make sense, to compare to 2 values. There is only one.

And the "find"-algorithm will do a comparison from both ends to find out, if a value is equal.

For inserting a new Example into the set, only `bool operator()(const Example& left, const Example& right) const` will be used.

For finding a value with `std::find`, first `bool operator()(const Example& left, const int& right) const` will be invoked and then `bool operator()(const int& left, const Example& right) const` will be called for the same pair.

`if(left.b == right) return left.a > right ? true: false;` in the first case will then always lead to a wrong result. And, for the second case the same. Here `if(left > right.b) return true;` will already lead to the wrong result.

---

Simply modify your code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Example
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    Example(int x, int y) { a = x; b = y; }
};

class Comparator
{
public:
    using is_transparent = true_type;

    bool operator()(const int& left, const Example& right) const
    {
        if (left > right.b) return true;
        return false;
    }

    bool operator()(const Example& left, const int& right) const
    {
        if (left.b > right) return true;
        return false;
    }

    bool operator()(const Example& left, const Example& right) const
    {
        if (left.b > right.b) return true;
        if (left.b == right.b) return left.a > right.a ? true : false;
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set<Example, Comparator> sa;
    sa.emplace(Example(4, 3));
    sa.emplace(Example(1, 2));
    sa.emplace(Example(5, 3));
    sa.emplace(Example(2, 7));
    sa.emplace(Example(3, 1));

    for (auto it = sa.begin(); it != sa.end(); it++)
        cout << it->a << " " << it->b << endl;

    cout << "Find: " << endl;
    auto it = sa.find(3);
    if (it != sa.end())
        cout << it->a << " " << it->b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will return *some* element with `b==3`, not necessarily the first one (one with the largest `a`). So not quite what the OP asked for, I think: "how can I find the first value"

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, correct. There is no other way with a customer comparator and a ````std::set````. With a function (or Lambda) it would be easily possible.

Comment: @ArminMontigny This explaination on operator method is much clear to me now. Is it possible if the data is sorted by `b` but finding the key the value of `a`?

Answer (score 2):

Make two changes. First, in heterogeneous comparison, compare the int value only with `b` component:

```
    bool operator()(const Example& left, int right) const
    {
        return left.b > right;
    }
```

(You won't need the mirror comparison in light of the second change we are about to make).

Second, use `lower_bound` in place of `find`:

```
auto it=sa.lower_bound(3);
if(it!=sa.end() && it->b == 3) { /* Found */ }
```

Note that we now have to additionally confirm that the element found has the correct `b` component; e.g. `sa.lower_bound(4)` would also find `{5, 3}` element. On the positive side, `lower_bound` is guaranteed to give us the first element in the sorted order, one with the largest `a`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WozsfGcc9)

Comment: Yes, as I have written. With a ````std::set```` and a custom comperator it will find some value with a 3. With an additional function it is completely simple. But then I do not need any comparator at all . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. My solution does too use a comparator, and does too find the value with `b==3` and the largest `a`, in logarithmic time. What is this "additional function" of which you speak?

Comment: With additional function I mean for example ````std::lower_bound````. Also my function will find 5,3. It will most probably always work. But it is implementation dependent . . .   But no worries. I find your solution super good. You explain all the background and that. So, +1

Comment: My solution doesn't use `std::lower_bound`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for your answer. It's pretty much near to my requirement. But is it possible if I need to find value of `a` whereas sorting is happening on `b`? I don't need the largest `a` but I need to sort as you mentioned above and find the value of `a` like 3 or others which is actually unique.

Comment: Not in logarithmic time, no. You can of course just linearly scan all elements, e.g. with `std::find_if`. I don't understand though - if you want to look up on `a`, why are you sorting on `b`? It's unclear what ultimate problem you are trying to solve; your question sounds more and more like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: ok, suppose there is a set of data with key and value. Now need to insert the value with sorted manner one by one and find any key on run time of the insertion. What is the best solution in case of complexity. The previous value can be changed by other insertion.

Comment: Then you probably don't want a map from key to value - you want a map from value to key to begin with. That is, what you call "value" should in fact be the key in the map, and what you call "key" should in fact be the value. Unless there are other requirements you neglected to mention.

Comment: There is an array with frequency and the frequency is incremented randomly. Now need the sorted array along with the index previously mapped with frequency. I actually try to find the solution with STL. I think heap sort is something like this. Need to insert and heapify and then if I need to find the value just need to traverse within logarithmic time. But it is not mapped with the key. I don't know the value but the key I can use to find and even I need the whole sorted data for another task.

Comment: Have a set of `{frequency, index}` pairs. Whenever you need to update the frequency, remove the pair with the old value from the set, then update, then insert the new pair. The set will maintain pairs ordered by frequency.

Comment: yes, what I'm trying to do is exactly you are saying. There is an additional requirement. If the frequency is same then greater index should be inserted first.

Comment: `std::set<std::pair<int, int>, std::greater<std::pair<int, int>>>` would do that for you. (Where the first component of the pair is the frequency, and the second is the index). The first element of this set, aka `*myset.begin()`, would report the highest index with the highest frequency.

Comment: so, I need to find the index everytime when I inserted and incremented frequency. I used sa.lower_bound({INT_MIN, 3}); It's found nothing. So, let me know how can I find with index in that case? or how can be updated the frequency in logarithmic time if possible when I have only index?

Comment: Right before you update the frequency, don't you have the previous value? Use that to find and erase the element from the set. Then update the frequency. Then insert the {new frequency, index} pair back into the set.

Comment: I've only index to update the frequency. And if you mean I need to find by frequency, there is a lots of similar frequency now. And there is another meaning, I need to map another array O(n) size for finding both value parallel and then find that pair on set then update it, is the solution I've understood now. Cause I cannot find by index only I told you above or if I need to get by frequency, I need another map or array for pair search.

Comment: You said "there is an array with frequency". I understood that to mean something like "int frequencies[N];` and you "update the frequency" by doing something like `frequencies[some_index] = new_value;` If that's what you meant, then you can access a frequency by index as in `frequencies[some_index]`. If that's **not** what you meant, then you totally lost me and I don't at all understand the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: And here sorted data means sorted by frequency in descending order.

Comment: I think we are looping in the query. Let me clear once. I need sorted data with updating frequency in runtime. I'm trying now. `std::set<std::pair<int, int>, std::greater<std::pair<int, int>>> sa; as {frequency,index}`. There is no other array. I inserted first `sa.insert({0, 3});` then again `3` comes to update hence I need to find index value by `3`, then erase it to insert the value again `sa.insert({0+1,3});` In this case, without find index `3` I don't know the frequency of `3` cause there is no other array. So, when I try to find it with `sa.lower_bound({INT_MIN,3});` doesn't get it.

Comment: Well, you do need an array or some other mapping from index to frequency, in addition to this set.

Comment: Hm, got it. I need auxiliary memory O(n) and it's working now. Thanks for the help :)